# Vue router security of routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm learning Vue for 2 weeks now and I cannot find an answer to this question about routing security.

When I'm securing routes in Vue with the meta fields and a routing guard like in the examle I wonder what a client could do to see the components still.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'bar',
          component: Bar,
          // a meta field
          meta: { requiresAuth: true }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})



router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // check if authenticated by jwt from store or localstorage
})
```

The route `/foo/bar` is protected by the beforeEach hook and the requiresAuth metafield. But all this code is on clientside (as minified version, but still there). A user could alter the code and see the component.
I know that I have to protect all the api routes on the Backend again so that the user can't get any private information. But a user could **possibly** see the protected component.
As I see it there is no way to hide a component from a user 100% secure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the user alters the *frontend* code, then the **component** would be viewable, yes.

But the **data** that would populate that component should *not be viewable* due to the backend restricting access to such data.

If the backend does not restrict it, it is a big security flaw, independently of Vue (the attacker could request from the API **directly** without a JS client).

As far as routes, the authentication you are doing is more of a workflow/usability concern. This is because, in general, there's no way to prevent altering of frontend code. You can do minification + uglification to make it more difficult, but that's about it. (Usually the minification is done to improve performance, not even for security reasons.)

Have a look at [**Vue-Router/Lazy Loading Routes**](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html) if you want to break your app in chunks:

> When building apps with a bundler, the JavaScript bundle can become quite large, and thus affect the page load time. It would be more efficient if we can split each route's components into a separate chunk, and only load them when the route is visited.

Technically, you could secure a chunk, having it available for download only to specific permissions. You should ask yourself if the work necessary to achieve this is really worth it, though
.

Comment: Thanks! That was what I'm looking for.
I Know, that I have to secure the Backend, but I wondered if the component without the backend data **could** be visible.

Comment: Yeah, it could. Unless you do that "chunk securing" part I mention in the end. But I don't even know if it is built in in the frameworks (I'm guessing not). By the way, security and validation should always happen in the backend as well, as, you know, a malicious user could circunvent such restrictions when they are at the frontend only.

Comment: In my app I have no need to secure some components, but imagine a component for the admins that has a header with the title "co-workers to fire". An employee should *not be able* to see that this component even exists.  
The lazy Loading sounds quite nice for such kind of a problem.  
Thanks for clarification!

Comment: In that case I'd have the title be a kind of data that comes from the backend.

Comment: One thing I do not understand is that if the component is view-able due to front-end tampering and the created() hook in that component fetches the data from let's say firestore, how should the data be secured when the hacker runs the altered page from his computer, because technically it is the same component requesting the data?

Comment: It is the same component, but you have to provide credentials (via JWT for example) to the backend to receive the data. An altered page would get a 401 unauthorized when requesting the protected data without providing credentials.

Comment: I'm still searching for a solution. Splitting into chunks doesn't solve the problem, because you need to restrict the access on your server, where you might run into issues, such as: "How do I set headers for the import?" - also a question asked without answer. ...HELP!?

Comment: @Fusseldieb perhaps set the identification in a cookie, which should get sent when requesting the chunk. You'd probably need some custom code, though, to handle it in your backend (the one serving the chunks).

Comment: @acdcjunior This approach actually worked!! If I send a cookie from the Express server, the browser sends it back, no matter if it came from Vue-Webpack or Axios. The only downside: You can't use JWT (at least in a traditional way), but it finally works, that's what matters! Thank you so much for that tip. I'll write an answer to this question later (when it really works, currently I'm only testing). I'm currently writing an "app.use" which checks for requested js-filenames, check if a auth cookie exists and if it's valid, it'll let the file through. The js obv. needs to be splitted by routes.

Comment: I joke you not, @acdcjunior, **nobody** has (had) a solution for this, as ridiculous as it seems. Everyone just circumvents the questions saying that a frontend-check is enough and if the API is protected, it should be enough - but in reality it doesn't work this way. The cookie approach, now that you mentioned it, seemed so basic(?) that I didn't even thought about that. I was overcomplicating (JWT, headers and such)